# Run ember-cli, including new, locally

Tags: ember.js, npm, ember-cli

I would like to run ember-cli, including new, locally.

If I run:
`npm install ember-cli`

then in the same folder, according to [this](https://discuss.emberjs.com/t/multiple-versions-of-ember-cli/7247) run:
`./node_modules/.bin/ember build`
This should work locally.

However, if I run `/node_modules/.bin/ember new something`, I get the following error:
`You cannot use the new command inside an ember-cli project.`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a valid error you would get no matter if you ran it globally or locally.

Running `ember new` creates a new ember project including the directory structure and you are not allowed to create an ember project within another ember project.

Comment: Ok cool, so I have to be outside of that folder with the local version of ember to create a new ember project.  A bit weird but will have to do.  Thanks!

Comment: Well, thats nothing you should do. `ember new` actually makes only sense with an globally installed `ember-cli`. If you want to bootstrap an `ember-cli` application in an existing folder use `ember init`. So basically `ember new foo` is identical to `mkdir foo;cd foo;npm install ember-cli;ember init;`.

Comment: @Lux, thanks!  I read that too, and tried it, but I was getting the following error: `The 'ember init' command requires a package.json in current folder with name attribute or a specified name via arguments. For more details, use 'ember help'.`  However, I realized that I had a package file that was not formatted correctly in my current folder.  When I removed it, then it worked as you instructed.  Thanks again!